# Change set from {a-b,b-c,c-a} to {(a,b),(b,c),(c,a)}?

Tags: python

```
v = input("enter the vertices: ")
v = [x.strip(' ') for x in v.split(',')]

e = input("enter the edges: ")
e = [x.strip(' ') for x in e.split(',')]

edges = set(e)
print(edges)
```

as the title says, I want to change the set to from the output `{'a-b', 'c-a', 'b-c'}` to `{('a','b'),('b','c'),('c','a')}` so it is easier to reference the data as edges. How would I do this?

Comment: Just use `tuple(x.strip().split('-'))` for the edges.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, it belongs to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-rout‌​e-for-a-dissociation-request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For converting `{'a-b', 'c-a', 'b-c'}` to `{('a','b'),('b','c'),('c','a')}`, you may use a *generator expression* to split each string item in your set based on `-` as:

```
>>> input_set = {'a-b','b-c','c-a'}

#                     v `str.split()` returns list. And list are non-hashable.
#                     v type-cast it to tuple in order to use it with `set`.
>>> output_Set = set(tuple(s.split('-')) for s in input_set)
>>> output_Set
{('c', 'a'), ('b', 'c'), ('a', 'b')}
```

However, you need not to create a set of strings. If you want to create the desired set at the first iteration, you may do:

```
v = set(x.strip().split('-') for x in v.split(','))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply parse the edges using a *set comprehension* and splitting on `'-'`:

```
e = input("enter the edges: ")
e = {tuple(x.strip().split('-')) for x in e.split(',')}
```